# error Objects are not valid as react child in react native, when i call async function in render method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-native-flatlist

i am calling this function in Render method in React Native code, but it shows the error, 
objects are not valid as react child

```
display = async () => {
    a="Hellow";
    return a;
}

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{await this.display()}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this.display to be async, so this could be written as

```
display = () => {
    a = "Hellow";
    return a;
}

render() {
    const display = this.display();
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{display}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Furthermore, if you are trying to do something asynchronously to change what is rendered, it should be done in the componentDidMount method. This is where you would set the state for the component.

```
async componentDidMount {
    ...
    const display = await fetchData(url);
    this.setState({ display });
}

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.display}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: issue is that , i am calling function inside flat list, every time i want to call async function with difrent parameters

Comment: Is it in reaction to a user action, like a click?

Comment: no , when ever the the app loads with this function it showa the error

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to store the text you want to display in state in the componentDidMount function and then render it like this rather than running a function in the render method:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    a = "hellow"
    this.setState({ text: a })
}

render () {
    return (
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
    )
}
```

Comment: the question i added is exampelary, actualy i want to fetch api through async function and want to call that function in render method.